# How to load HTML template instead of json using react-email-editor?

Tags: reactjs

I am using [react-email-editor](https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor) to edit email templates. Now I want to save template data in html format and also want to load html data in editor.
As react-email-editor is loading data in json format(I have used onLoad function and passes json data in it), but now the question is how can I load editor data using html.

Is there any method to convert html to json format using this package?

Or if there is any other method to do this please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Details:
https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor/blob/master/demo/src/example/index.js

Even though its been above 1 year, someone might find it useful later:

```
 const emailEditorRef = useRef(null);
 const saveDesign = () => {
     emailEditorRef.current.editor.saveDesign((design) => {
      console.log('saveDesign', design);
      alert('Design JSON has been logged in your developer console.');
   });
 };

 const exportHtml = () => {
     emailEditorRef.current.editor.exportHtml((data) => {
       const { design, html } = data;
       console.log('exportHtml', html);
       alert('Output HTML has been logged in your developer console.');
     });
 };


<button onClick={saveDesign}>Save Design</button>
<button onClick={exportHtml}>Export HTML</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.